# Magento 2 rest api - Client denied by server configuration

Tags: magento2, apache2, rest-api

I am using magento rest api to manage cart. My frontend runs on reactjs. 
Here is my apache virtual host looks like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento/pub

        <Directory /var/www/html/magento/pub>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess in pub folder is same as - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.2-develop/pub/.htaccess

When I am adding anything to cart using : POST - http://localhost/magento/rest/V1/carts/mine
I am getting the error 404 in response.
I checked the apache log and found this

```
Client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/magento/pub/rest
```

All other api's are working.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You permissions might not be correct. Try to set the permissions as described in the [Magento 2 DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the 404 response from POSTing or PUTing to an API endpoint, in our case "Require all granted" was needed in the .htaccess file too